# extract last 5 products mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how to extract from the mysql database the last 3 products added (by date)?

structure:

```
id  name      date
1    xx     01.01.2001
2    yy     02.02.2002
3    zz     03.03.2003
4    aa     01.01.2004
5    bb     02.02.2005
6    cc     03.03.2006
```

interogation will return this rows:

```
4    xx     01.01.2004
5    yy     02.02.2005
6    zz     03.03.2006
```

Who can help me?
p.s. sorry for my english :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: your example set of results doesn't match the data in the table

Comment: What about `SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT    id, name, date
FROM      TABLENAME
ORDER BY  date DESC
LIMIT     0, 3
```

Comment: +1 but NB, this returns the correct results but not in the order in which OP suggested.

Comment: I thought that's what it is asked, that the result set was wrongly typed to the question

Comment: I suspect this too, but it's worth making clear because they might want the results the way they listed them.